# SQL select * from teachers except where teacherID = teacher

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to select all of the values data from a table except for one row. How do I do this?

```
table = teachers
headers = TeacherID, Password, FirstName, Surname
TeacherID = teacher
```

When I try

```
SELECT * 
FROM teachers 
EXCEPT 
SELECT * 
FROM teachers 
WHERE TeacherID = 'teacher'
```

I get the error

> `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT * FROM teachers WHERE TeacherID = teacher LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1`

Comment: `select * from teachers where TeacherID != 'teacher'`

Comment: MySQL does not support `EXCEPT`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name @fancyPats Those are not the issue hier. Read the error message. The parser stumbles over the `SELECT` at the beginning.

Comment: What did you do prior to this SELECT statement? There is something strange here.

Comment: This SQL does not correspond to the error message you posted.  Post the SQL code you attempted to execute.

Comment: @arkascha; error msg is correct with the context here. error stumbles before `select` cause it finds the `except` keyword which is not present in MySQL. It's erroring in the second select part.

Comment: @dodexahedron True, though I suspect this is just the result of making many tries. That error message looks _funny_...

Comment: @Rahul Then I would expect mysql to output "... right syntax neat 'EXCEPT..."

Comment: @arkascha: that doesn't change the fact that the statement will *never* run on MySQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I partly agree, that actually depends on the mysql version. But anyway, this is another issue.

Comment: @arkascha: No, it does not depend on the version. There is no MySQL version that supports the `except` operator

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name when I try this: `SELECT * FROM user EXCEPT something;` I get this error: `... for the right syntax to use near 'something' at line 1`. So the server does not stumble over the EXCEPT. It might be a mariadb server which most people call a mysql server too. Which makes sense, actually. And which _does_ support `EXCEPT`.

Comment: @arkascha, it will not error saying right syntax neat 'EXCEPT...". see here to examine that http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2736e/4. BTW, OP's posted query and error are irrelevant.

Comment: @Rahul I am still doing that. Funny enough: I get different results, depending on the exact statement I try. There seems to be a deeper problem in the parser here. Indeed your fiddle does output the above error message. In other situations the `'` is at another position, which puzzles me.

Comment: I agree that _most likely_ the problem is the `EXCEPT` here. Though there are other possibilities. @AaronDennis which mysql flavor/version do you use?

Comment: @arkascha: MariaDB also does not support `except`. Do you know what `except` does? Because `SELECT * FROM user EXCEPT something` would be invalid even for a DBMS that supports that. It's the "opposite" operation to a `union` so it needs **two** queries: `select a,b from foo except select a,b from bar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should it either

```
select * from teachers where TeacherID != 'teacher'
```

OR

```
select * from teachers where TeacherID not in ('teacher','teacher1','teacher2')
```

Answer (score 0):

This will select all rows where column `TeacherID` does not contain value `teacher`

```
Select * from teachers where TeacherID != 'teacher'
```

I'm not sure if your column TeacherID is string, if so do not name it ID. IDs are usually int data type.

If you want to select all records where column `TeacherID` contains value `teacher` do this

```
SELECT * 
FROM teachers 
WHERE TeacherID = 'teacher'
```